# Exit code when a process is invoked by "START" command and is killed by TASKKILL

Tags: windows, perl, taskkill

Say I have a script `parent.pl` calling another script `child.pl` using `system` and `start` commands, like this:

```
# parent.pl
system("START \"CHILD\" /WAIT perl child.pl");
print "$?\n";
```

Child.pl is running an operation which takes a long time:

```
# child.pl
while (1) {}
```

Now I use `TASKKILL` to terminate `child.pl`.

```
TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq CHILD"
```

Surprisingly, the exit code printed by `parent.pl` is `0`. However, if I just call `child.pl` in `parent.pl` instead of using `START` command, the exit code would be `256`.

```
# parent.pl
system("perl child.pl");
print "$?\n";
```

Does `START` always exit with code `0` even if it's killed? Is there any way to let it exit with the "right" code, like `256`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't use `START`. Launch the child process directly. Execution in the parent will block until the child is finished.

Prefer [IPC::System::Simple](http://p3rl.org/IPC%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aSimple) over the built-in core function `system`.

Comment: A "feature" of `START` is that it runs the process in a new console.

Comment: But I need to start `child.pl` in another console (`parent.pl` calls multiple children, a single console will mess up the information)